# How to install Postman Native on Ubuntu ?

Tags: ubuntu, postman

I have tried below steps, but it doesn't work for me :

(1) `wget https://dl.pstmn.io/download/latest/linux64 -O postman.tar.gz`

(2) `sudo tar -xzf postman.tar.gz -C /opt`

(3) `rm postman.tar.gz`

(4) `sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman`

Refer to : 
[How to install/start Postman native v4.10.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996358/how-to-install-start-postman-native-v4-10-3-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-64-bit)
.
When I tried step 4, i met following error :
"ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/postman': File exists"

Then I searched for more information, then I tried this command : 
`sudo unlink /usr/bin/utserver` output these error "unlink: cannot unlink '/usr/bin/utserver': No such file or directory".

Again i tried another command `sudo rm /usr/bin/utserver` then output these error "rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/utserver': No such file or directory"
.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The error is just saying the symbolic link you tried to create already exists ... so just remove it

```
ls -la /usr/bin/postman  #  issue this to confirm it exists

sudo rm /usr/bin/postman  #  remove it if it exists
```

now just run your (4) command again

```
sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman
```

confirm install worked by issuing

```
which  postman  # if installed it will say :  /usr/bin/postman
```